# How to have best use of Python lists?

Tags: python, list

My question is te following:
I'm new to Python programming and I'm a little confused about the correct use of lists.
When I want for example to create a list of 10 elements I am doing something like:

```
list = [None for x in range(10)]
```

And when I have something to put on it, I do:

```
list[lastPosition] = data
```

But after some research I noticed that this use for lists is not efficient or recommended. But how other way could a list be inicialized before I have all the data? My idea is to have a list (specially something like Java's Collections) inicialized and as the data comes I fill it.
I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: `list = []; list.append(data)` if you want a growing list? If you want your list to be of a fixed size, there's nothing wrong with filling it with `None`. (Easier as `list = [None] * 10`, though.)

Comment: @Ryan This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you. I didn't know that this list could be dynamic

Comment: `list = [None] * 10` works for a list of references to *immutable* values; trying something like `list = [[]] * 10` is an error waiting to happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know in advance how many elements will be in the list,
then don't try to allocate 10 elements. Start with an empty list and use the `append` function to append to it:

```
lst = []
...
lst.append(value)
```

If for some reason you really need to initialize a list to a constant size,
*and the initial elements are immutable values*,
then you can do that like this:

```
lst = [None] * 10
```

If the initial elements are mutable values,
you most probably don't want to use this technique,
because all the elements will all point to the same instance.
In that case your original technique is mostly fine as it was:

```
lst = [SomeClass() for _ in range(10)]
```

Note that I renamed the variable from `list` to `lst`,
because `list` is a built-in class in Python,
and it's better to avoid such overlaps.

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for the answer and for the tips. It's exactly what I was looking for. I was only initializing with a constant size because I didn't know the method append. Seems like I need to pay better attention to documentations.